# How to link an automatically updating model object with Django Template Language

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm making a blog, on the index page I have a list that links every single blog post with some details about it

```
        <ul>
        {% for post in object_list %}    
            <li><a href="{% url 'article_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> - {{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}<br/>
            {{ post.summary }}</li>  {{ post.adventure_date }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now what I want is on the home page to have a featured article section that will automatically update with the two most recently posted articles without having to manually change the code every time the posts are added. I'm struggling to come up with a solution to this, I'm thinking that I would create another variable in my model that was like
featured = BooleanField(default=True)

But I'm not sure how the true or false would be automatically updated without me going into django admin and manually checking the boxes each time it needed updated

Comment: simply use Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:2] to get the two latest articles

Answer (score 0):

this was accomplished using djangos built in slice filter

```
{% for post in object_list|slice:":2" %}    
                        <li><a href="{% url 'article_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> - {{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}<br/>
                        {{ post.summary }}</li>  {{ post.adventure_date }}<br/>
                        {% endfor %}
```

and then simply modifying the homeview from a function to a class based list view